# I am having difficulties with analysing steroids in GC/MS

Tags: chromatography

Is there anyone here that has already analysed estrone and 17beta-estradiol on GC/MS (HP5-MS column and MSTFA as derivatizing agent)?
Is it necessary to make a mixture of other reagents with MSTFA or can I just use MSTFA in the process of derivatization? How long does that process take to happen?